# Can a protein complex be a machine?

Tags: terminology, proteins

Discussing an article with friends we began discussing whether a protein complex that punches holes in cells (membrane attack complex) would be considered a machine.

Now, my friends are biochemistry students while I am a computer science student so this is far from my expertise. In my imagination this would be a mechanical action, hence the definition of a machine found on Wikipedia.
My friends counter argument is more of an emotional one, saying it feels wrong to call it a machine but also couldn't come up with a better word.

So:
Is it a machine? Is it something else? Or is a complex just a complex?
Does chemistry/biology have its very own definitions for things that do stuff in coordination without being "alive"?

Comment: If some gaseous molecules collide, they can react to form a new compound, given they have enough energy and the right orientation. Would you call the reactants a machine?

Comment: I might argue that for the distinction to be meaningful the issue would be whether a protein is manipulating something *chemical* (eg breaking bonds selectively) or *physical* (eg moving some other object or punching a hole in something without breaking specific bonds).

Comment: @M.A.R. Not necessarily, I guess. But what about a protein that fold under light. Is that not technically converting energy to mechanical motion?

Comment: I would generalize that a machine can transform chemical energy (or other form) into mechanical energy, and can operate in a cycle, eventually returning to its original state.

Comment: @NightWriter so you would consider it a machine given it can revert and repeat the process?

Comment: @Harri That's how I think of one. Then again I suppose you could have a one-off (disposable) machine, probably I am imposing an unnecessary constraint with the cyclic business. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_machine#Biological

Comment: Ah, perfect article. If you were to post it as answer I'd mark it the correct one

Comment: Look for articles on the crystal  structure of ATPase, this has a rotor in the centre of the protein that performs chemistry as rotates and opens and closes different sites.

Comment: Not sure about the specific case but molecular machines do exist. Then is matter of some subtle definition. Muscles and bones are machine, small molecules can be seen as machines, proteins are just in between.  Besides the merely chemical bonding aspect, changes in geometry results in motion. Normally chemistry is non dealing with that. But once things are anchored or analysed at the proper scale,  they certainly become machines. Is the emphasis on this machine aspect that is not often needed. Exception are indeed biochemistry and (nano)material science.

Comment: @Harri — I think that the key here is that a machine is generally understood as "man-made" which is clearly not the case for a natural protein. However, man-made proteins might be considered as true machines.

Comment: @SteffX that is precisely the issue at hand in the discussion with my friends. We decided to call it a mechanism but based this solely on personal preference. I had addid this as an answer but it was pojnted out to me that personal preference does not fit the criteria for a useful answer on this site. Putting this general undestanding aside and going purely by (Oxford) definition, it should be understood as a machine I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Oxford dictionary, a machine is:

> An apparatus using mechanical power and having several parts, each with a definite function and together performing a particular task.

Based on that definition, I think some proteins and enzymes could definitely be considered machines. A good example for that, in my opinion, would be [ATP Synthase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_synthase) and all of the proteins that participate in the [oxidative phosphorilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxidative_phosphorylation) process.

Comment: According to to the Oxford dictionary, an [apparatus](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apparatus) is 1. **technical** equipment or machinery [....], 2.the complex structure of a particular organization or system. 3. A collection of notes [...] - I do not really see a good fit for proteins here. But if a protein isn't an apparatus, it's not a machine either...

Comment: Well, we can just keep going down the rabbit hole. According to the Oxford dictionary, [technical](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/technical) is: "Relating to a particular subject, art, or craft, or its techniques." Seems to fit. I guess there is no clear answer because it's a question that relies heavily on semantics.

Comment: :) Fully agree that this question heavily relies on semantics.

Comment: @Arsak Apparatus has much narrower meaning.